Solution of 1st Order DiffEq with Repeated Roots Using Linear Algebra
This is from Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang, section 6.3. We are trying to compute $e^{At}$, where $A$ is a square matrix and $t$ is time, when $A$ is not diagonalizable(repeated roots). The way the book does it is by writing $e^{At}$ as $e^{It}e^{(A-I)T}$, which makes sense, then writing this as $e^{t}[I+(A-I)t]$. This last step gets me really confused, can anyone please give me a hint or explanation? Any help is appcreciated!

Was the series expansion of the matrix exponential discussed, and was it also shown that in this case that $(A-I)^2$ (and therefore higher powers) are zero?

@messenger The series expansion was discussed, and it did say $(A-I)^2$ is 0. In fact the book calls it "Short Series" which I have no idea where it comes from. But now I see where it comes from, thanks for help!

@messenger This is a follow up question: Is it correct to say that for any non-diagonalizable A, $(A-I)^2=0$? In the book we have $\lambda =1$, so I see $(A-I)^2=0$. However, for another matrix say
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}. Then $(A-I)^2$ is not $0$. I think $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$ is correct. However, $e^{At}=e^t [I+(A-I)t]$ is correct, so I don't really know where the $(A-I)^2=0)$ comes from.

In that case you are right that $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$, so you would subtract $\lambda I$ and end up with $e^{At} = e^{\lambda t}(I+(A-\lambda I)t)$.

@messenger That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much
